# Remove textboxes in smartart grid design

Tags: powerpoint

I'm trying to make a square photo grid without textboxes using powerpoint photo design. The square grid includes textboxes with each photo that I don't want.  Can I get rid of the text boxes?

Comment: Have you tried PowerPoint's Insert | Photo Album feature? It will only go up to 4 photos per slide, but allows you to include/not include text beneath each image.

Comment: I need way more images than that.

Comment: Do you need this as part of a screen-show or as a printout/PDF?

Comment: I'll need it as .jpg

Comment: This is a forum for help with writing programs, not using them; if you've attacked this problem by writing code, edit your original question to include what you've done so far. Otherwise, the sibling StackExchange forum, SuperUser is a better place to ask. Either way, describe what you're after FULLY. Otherwise you'll end up playing 20 questions as we seem to have started doing here. Most people will give up and go home before question 5.